# how to set up a setOnClickListener on a GroupView of EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I would like to insert my array of EditText, contained in a LinearLayout, in a ViewGroup so as to be able to set for all EditText the same setonclicklistener. How do I proceed?

This is the code for my attempt:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements  OnClickListener {

ViewGroup group;;
View v1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.xsubLayout);
for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
v1 = group.getChildAt(i);
if (v1 instanceof EditText) {
((EditText)v1).setOnClickListener(this);
}
}
```

and OnClick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

if(v == v1 ){
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v1.getWindowToken(), 0);


enableKeyboard();
}

}
```

but this way is not working. In practice Continues to see the Android keyboard instead of my custom keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement onClickListener() for your class.
For example like this.

```
  public class Main extends Activity implements  OnClickListener {

     EditText etText;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     etText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
     btnRemove.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   // Here you can perform same task for all the EditText.

}
  }
 }
```

Comment: @whiteTIGER So what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I have some EditText of which I should like to place in a GroupView, to manage their OnClick

Comment: @whiteTIGER I changed my post.This may help you.  :)

Comment: but the number of EditText generated by my app is then entered by the user is not standard. My app generates an array of EditText

Comment: @whiteTIGER Where ever you create EditText or you are inserting EditText which you create dynamically pass that id to etText and use OnCLickListener() for that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14896/discussion-between-akshay-and-whitetiger)